# Non bi partite matching algorithm

Tags: algorithm, matching

I'm trying to find a specific algorithm allowing me to match people depending of many criterias. All of them are in the same set, and edges cannot have common vertices. Basically like a dating website but as I said : only one set, so not bi partite.

Despite researches I wasn't able to find this algorithm, almost everything is about bipartite, or allow common vertices. I'm specifically looking for a perfect matching (that can be slow).

It seems the algorithm is supposed to be based on the Ford Furkerson algorithm (which usually is for bipartite matching), but I still don't get how to apply it to that. Do you have any clues ? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the maximum matching in a non-bipartite graph using the [Blossom algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blossom_algorithm) (it's quite complicated so I'll not describe it here).

Once you have the maximum matching, checking if it's perfect is very straightforward (just compare its size with the number of vertices in the graph).